# How to disable Ctools modal form from running on mobile devices?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using Drupal 7 [Totem](https://www.drupal.org/project/totem) distro (a responsive site). My problem is that the pop-up modal form works fine on large screens but doesn't respond well on mobile devices/smartphones.

How do I disable the modal form from runnning on mobile devices?

Answer (score 2):

You can hack wonders with a little "@mediaquery" and "!important". 
I used this little bit with "modal_forms", not sure if the #id is the same.

```
@media (max-width: 580px) { 
    #modalContent {
      position: fixed !important;
      top: 12% !important;
      bottom: 12% !important;
      right: 4% !important;
      left: 4% !important;
    }
    div.ctools-modal-content {
      width: 100% !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div.ctools-modal-content .modal-content {
      width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Next code will disable **ctools popup** appearing, and restore going to URL of link behaviour (tested for [Modal forms (with ctools)](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms)), so for mobiles, instead of opening modal, it will open URL of link:

```
if ( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $('a.ctools-use-modal-processed', context).unbind('click');
}
```